# How to best model external resources as Pod dependencies

Tags: kubernetes

I have a set of ephemeral networked devices that exist today.  These broadcast their availability and I have a service that knows all currently available resources.  Both the devices and this service exist outside of any Kubernetes cluster currently.

I’d like for there to be a 1:1 mapping between these ephemeral devices and a Pod.  As the devices come and go the number of Pod replicas should scale.

Apologies if I have this all wrong but based on my reading of how to extend Kubernetes it feels that:

1. I should model my devices with a Custom Resource Definition, e.g. EphemeralNetworkedDevice
2. My service tracking the available devices should be a Custom Resource Controller, e.g. EphemeralNetworkedDeviceController, which keeps the Kubernetes scheduler updated as to what EphemeralNetworkedDevices exist

What I absolutely cannot understand is how I can define the dependent relationship between my Pod and an EphemeralNetworkedDevice.  If these devices were Node-local I feel they could be modelled as Device Plugins, however I do not want to restrict my compute to a single Node.

Have I entirely misunderstood the extension model?  How can I go about creating this 1:1 relationship?

Comment: The logic sounds relatively simple. Have you considered using external metrics with horizontal pod autoscaler?

Comment: @eamon1234 thank you - this was helpful! I will likely do this to manage scaling (vs setting replicas to MAX_INT).  However, I still feel that modelling these devices as Kubernetes objects and creating a Pod:device dependency (if possible) will make life easier. Possibly in combination with the Operator model?

Comment: If there's other reasons for having that logic inside kubernetes (such as other controllers which listen for `EphemeralNetworkedDevice` attach events, audit logging etc, then by all means add a CRD. But if you're looking for the shortest path, and an auto-scaled deployment where the entrypoint and termination logic could query the device pool and get a device and release it back if destroyed, then you might get away with just that. If you were to go CRDs, then yes the only way would be via an operator (look at the SDKs kubebuilder or operator framework)

Comment: @lewiz did you manage to solve this?

Comment: @A_Suh - by creating custom controllers and resources. One creates/updates/deletes the ephemeral resources and the other listens for them and spins up Pods.

Comment: @lewiz would be great if you put more insights as an answer for the future community reference.Thank you!